# point node js app to domain

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I want to point a domain to the nodejs app running on 3000 port.
Currently my app is hosted on aws. If I have to point my domain to the app, so that I don't have to write `<domain>:<port_number>` in browser then I think I have two options:

1. use nginx to proxy the request to port 3000
2. use aws route 53 for the same

Correct me if I'm wrong and please suggest which one should I opt

Answer (score 1):

Route 53 is just a Domain Name Server. 
If you fire up a EC2 instance, you can reach it with the IP address. In addition you get a generic domain to connect to your EC2 instance, something like this: `ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`
This is ok for testing, but not for a production setup.

So if you want to point a more pleasant domain name to your instance, you need to edit the dns record on your DNS Server. For this you can use Route 53 or any other DNS Service like namecheap or iwantmyname.com.

You can't configure ports there, so use option 1 and set up nginx.

Of cause, as option 3 you can change the port of your nodejs app to port 80, but then you need to run it as root user and that is really bad practice!
So stick with nginx.

More about DNS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

Comment: okay, so I am left with only nginx as an option to point. So what is route 53 for ?

Comment: Thank you, one more thing

for example if my app is running on port 3000 and my db (mongodb) is running on port 27017 then how can I proxy both of them, so that I can connect to my app as well as database.

Comment: For security reasons i would't forward the mongodb port. If you need to connect to the mongodb for debugging or so, just ssh into the machine and temporarily forward the port over ssh, but this is a little bit to off-topic now.